# Use the Fetch API to include an XML file transformed with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, fetch-api

I have an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                     
<?xml-stylesheet href="trans.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>                                                                          
<profile>                                                                            
  <name>Leonard</name>                                                                            
  <age>99</age>                                                                             
</profile>
```

with its `xslt` transformation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                          
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>                                                                                                            
    <xsl:template match="profile"> 
        <form>            
            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">                                                                     
                <label>                                                                                     
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>:                                                                
                    <input name="{name()}" type="text" />                                      
                </label>                                                                                                                          
                <br />                                                                                                                            
            </xsl:for-each>                                                                                                                       
        </form>                                                                                                                                   
    </xsl:template>                                                                                                                               
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I use the Fetch API to get the already transformed content in the DOM?
This example

```
fetch('ref.xml', {})                                                                                                                              
    .then(response => response.text())                                                                                                            
    .then(str => {                                                                                                                                
        (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml")  
        const app = document.getElementById("content"); 
        app.innerHTML = str;                                                                                                                      
    })
```

Returns the XML not transformed.

**PS**: I want to use this method as apparently jQuery is being less popular, the HTML5 imports feature will be removed in the future (and they do not work on my browser), and finally the `<object> <embed> <iframe>` tags do allow me to inherit the css and access the inner tags.

Comment: "to get the already transformed content"? Which tool should have already transformed the content? You can feed the XML and XSLT to XSLTProcessor and use the `transformToFragment` or `transformToDocument` method to run the transformation. There is no XSLT processing triggered by the HTTP request your fetch call does.

Answer (score 2):

You are not restricted to XSLT 1 but can use XSLT 3 based on Saxon-JS 2 in the browser:

```js
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                     
<?xml-stylesheet href="trans.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>                                                                          
<profile>                                                                            
  <name>Leonard</name>                                                                            
  <age>99</age>                                                                             
</profile>`;

const xslt = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                          
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>                                                                                                            
    <xsl:template match="profile"> 
        <form>            
            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">                                                                     
                <label>                                                                                     
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>:                                                                
                    <input name="{name()}" type="text" />                                      
                </label>                                                                                                                          
                <br />                                                                                                                            
            </xsl:for-each>                                                                                                                       
        </form>                                                                                                                                   
    </xsl:template>                                                                                                                               
</xsl:stylesheet>`;

const transformationResult = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`transform(
    map {
      'source-node' : parse-xml($xml),
      'stylesheet-text' : $xslt,
      'delivery-format': 'raw'
    }
  )?output`,
  [],
  { params : {
     xml : xml,
     xslt : xslt
  }}
);

const app = document.getElementById("content"); 
app.textContent = '';
app.appendChild(transformationResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/js/SaxonJS2.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Without precompiling the XSLT to SEF/JSON this works synchronously with an on the fly compilation of the XSLT, thus if you know the XSLT will always be the same it helps running it through the Node.js `xslt3` tool (or Saxon EE) with `-export:trans.xsl.sef.json -nogo -xsl:trans.xsl` and then you can even run the XSLT transformation asynchronously using `SaxonJS.transform` (https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!api/transform).